# Comparing different conditions on a binomial distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, group-differences, small-sample, type-i-and-ii-errors

I have some data where I have tested a binomial random variable under 4 conditions. The null hypothesis is that they all have equal means, alternative hypothesis is that one or more means differ from the others.
What kind of test can I use to compare the means of each condition? Sample size for each condition is quite small (under 20), but if it is necessary, then I can get more.
The data look like:
$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}\rm{Condition}&A&B&C&D\\\hline\rm{Successes}&9&8&4&12\\\rm{Fails}&4&4&3&7\end{array}$$

Comment: Instead of using fancy methods, have you tried just computing the _numerical_ values of the success rates of the four cases, that is, $9/(9+4), 8/(8+4), 4/(4+3), 12/(12+7)$ to see if anything is glaringly obvious? Hint: the first decimal digit might be looked at....

Comment: Are you looking for a pairwise test or an omnibus test that all are equal against the alternative that at least one of the population proportions differs from another?

Comment: As for sample size, you'll likely need *much* larger samples to tell them apart, I'd suggest somewhere along the lines of 15-30 times as many observations to have a reasonable chance of picking up differences of small size. For example, if the true proportions for two of the samples were 0.6 and 0.7, you'd want about 200 observations for each sample to have a good chance of picking up a difference, perhaps a bit more if the other proportions lie in between the two. If you have the option, increase the smallest sample sizes, as that brings the most benefit.

Comment: This is not a test of a null versus a single alternative but rather a decision problem with 5 different hypotheses: the null $H_0$ that all four samples are from the same binomial distribution and hypotheses $H_A, H_B, H_C, H_D$ that samples $A, B, C, D$ respectively are from a different distribution than the others (which are all from the same distribution). While the sample sizes are small and larger samples would be better, that $H_C$ is the true hypothesis is a reasonably defensible decision.

Comment: @dilip-sarwate Surely this is analygous to an anova test with 4 groups where there is the null hypothesis "all groups are from the same population" and the null hypothesis "at least one group is different"

Comment: @user27271 _At least one group is different_ is not the same hypothesis as _Exactly one group is different._  I interpreted your statement `one or means differ from the others.` as having an obvious typo in that you meant to write `one of the means differs from the others.`  (which implicitly says that three means are the same and one is different). So please edit your problem statement to clarify what _exactly_ you want to know.

Comment: @dilip-sarwate Oh sorry about that, I meant to say "one or more means differ from the others"

Answer (score 3):

Overall you have 33 successes and 18 failures.  So if the means are the same, you would expect the numbers of successes in each case to be close to $\frac{33}{51}$ of the attempts in each case, respectively 13, 12, 7, and 19, so giving the numbers

```r
     8.412    4.588
     7.765    4.235
     4.529    2.471
    12.294    6.706
```

These are very close to what you have observed: the biggest difference is below $0.6$, which is very small given that your observations are integers.  So any reasonable hypothesis test will not reject the null hypothesis of the means being the same.

More generally, you are looking at a [contingency table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table). So you might want to consider something like a [chi-squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) (though some cells are small) or a [Fisher exact test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test).

***Added:*** some simple R code

```r
> dat <- rbind(c(9,4), c(8,4), c(4,3), c(12,7))
> dat
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    9    4
[2,]    8    4
[3,]    4    3
[4,]   12    7
> chisq.test(dat)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  dat 
X-squared = 0.332, df = 3, p-value = 0.9539

Warning message:
In chisq.test(dat) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
> fisher.test(dat)

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  dat 
p-value = 0.9758
alternative hypothesis: two.sided 
> dat-outer(rowSums(dat),colSums(dat),"*")/sum(dat)
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.5882353 -0.5882353
[2,]  0.2352941 -0.2352941
[3,] -0.5294118  0.5294118
[4,] -0.2941176  0.2941176
```

Comment: Given frequencies below 5 in some cells, [Fisher's exact test is preferable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Problems), but [not uncontroversial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test#Controversies).

Answer (score 1):

Here's R code for testing this with Fisher's exact test (set `B` lower on slow computers):

```r
fisher.test(matrix(c(9, 8, 4, 12, 4, 4, 3, 7), byrow=TRUE, nrow=2, 
            ncol=4), simulate.p.value=TRUE, B=10000000)
```

Like @Henry suggested, very weak evidence against the null: $p=.98$.

You may wish to consider [some controversy about Fisher's exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test#Controversies), but I don't think they apply here.